# How to prove that $xyz$ is a perfect square given that $\frac{xy}{z}+ \frac{yz}{x} + \frac{zx}{y} \in \mathbb Z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x,y$, and $z$ are relatively prime positive integers where $\frac{xy}{z} +\frac{yz}{x} + \frac{zx}y$ is also an integer. Prove that $xyz$ is a perfect square.

What I've Tried: I arranged the information on the fractions to get $xyz(1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2) = k$ for some integer k but am stuck from this point forward.

Edit: $x,y,z$ need not be "pairwise" relatively prime. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be integers with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ such that
$$t=\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{xz}{y}+\frac{yz}{x},$$
is an integer. Giving the fractions a common denominator, we find that
$$t=\frac{(xy)^2+(xz)^2+(yz)^2}{xyz}.\tag{1}$$
Let $u:=\gcd(y,z)$ and $v:=\gcd(x,z)$ and $w:=\gcd(x,y)$ so that $x$ is divisible by $v$ and $w$, and $y$ is divisible by $u$ and $w$, and $z$ is divisible by $u$ and $v$. Note that
$$\gcd(u,v)=\gcd(u,w)=\gcd(v,w)=\gcd(x,y,z)=1,$$
so it follows that $x=vwX$ and $y=uwY$ and $z=uvZ$ for some integer $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Because $X$ divides $x$ it is clear that $X$ is coprime to $u=\gcd(y,z)$, and similary $Y$ is coprime to $v$ and $Z$ is coprime to $w$. Moreover we now have
$$\gcd(X,Y)=\gcd(X,Z)=\gcd(Y,Z)=1.$$
Plugging this back into $(1)$, with a bit of algebra we see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
t&=&\frac{(xy)^2+(xz)^2+(yz)^2}{xyz}\\
&=&\frac{(uvw^2XY)^2+(uv^2wXZ)^2+(u^2vwYZ)^2}{u^2v^2w^2XYZ}\\
&=&\frac{(wXY)^2+(vXZ)^2+(uYZ)^2}{uvwXYZ}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In particular, we see that $X$ divides the numerator
$$(wXY)^2+(vXZ)^2+(uYZ)^2.$$
Because the first two squares are divisible by $X$, also the last square is divisible by $X$. But we already saw that $u$, $Y$ and $Z$ are all coprime to $X$. It follows that $X=1$, and by the exact same argument also $Y=Z=1$. Then $x=vw$ and $y=uw$ and $z=uv$ and so $xyz=(uvw)^2$ is a perfect square.

Comment: I got $t=  \frac{(wXY)^2+(vXZ)^2+(uYZ)^2}{XYZ}  $ just before "In particular."   Before "Moreover we now have"  I recommend pointing out that $\gcd( \frac{x}{w},  \frac{y}{w}) = 1$   so that $\gcd(vX, uY) = 1$  and  $\gcd(X, Y) = 1$

Answer (score 4):

This is a re-working of the Answer from @Marco.

The proposition holds if $xyz=1.$

If $xyz>1,$let $p$ be any prime divisor of $xyz.$ Let $p^a$ be the largest power of $p$ to divide any one of $x,y,z$ and WLOG suppose $p^a|x.$ Referring to the work in the Answer by @Marco, we may suppose WLOG that $p^b$ is the largest power of $p$ to divide $y,$ with $1\le b$ and also $b\le a$ (by the maximality of $a$).

So $p^{a+b}$ is the largest power of $p$ to divide $xyz$ because g$cd(x,y,z)=1.$ We wish to show that $a+b$ is even.

Since $b\le a$, we have, as in @Marco, $p^{a+b}|p^{2a}|(xz)^2$ and $p^{a+b}|p^{2a}|(xy)^2 .$

So, as in @Marco, we have $p^{a+b}\,|xyz\,|(yz)^2=2^{2b}(y/2^b)^2z^2$ with $p\not |(y/2^b)\in\Bbb N$ and with $p\not|z.$ This implies $a+b\le 2b.$ But we have $b\le a.$ So $a=b.$ So $a+b$ is even.

2

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the fraction as

$$
\frac{(xy)^2+(yz)^2+(xz)^2}{xyz}
$$
Let $p$ a prime factor of $x$. We know that it has to divide one between $y$ and $z$ because the fraction is an integer. We know that it can't divide both because the numbers are relatively prime.

w.l.o.g. assume it divides $y$. Simplifying the fraction and calling $x=px',y=py'$ we obtain
$$
\frac{(x'y)^2+(y'z)^2+(x'z)^2}{x'y'z}
$$
By repeating the process for all the prime factors of $x$ we obtain that any factor is a factor of $y$ or $z$, but not both. By repeating the process for $y$ and $z$ we obtain that any prime factor that divide one of the three numbers divides exactly one of the other numbers, i.e. any prime factor on $xyz$ appears with an even power, so it is a perfect square.

Comment: "We know that it has to divide one between y and z because the fraction is an integer" . I did not understand anything.

Comment: @user1176861 $p$ divides $x$ so It divides the denominator of the fraction, because by hypothesis the fraction Is an integer $p$ has to divide the numerator. But $p$ divide 2 of the addendum so It has to divide the third, too i.e. It divides $(yz)^2$

Comment: +1.  have given an answer that is a re-working of yours, as it seemed to me that it could be clarified, and to put it as a comment would not give me enough time to fix my own endless supply of typos.

Comment: @user1176861 . See my answer, which is this one re-written.

Comment: What do you mean by repeating the process? The new formula is different from the original one, so you can’t just “repeat” it. How do you know that we don’t have p (and no more p’s) divides $x$ and $p^2$ (and no more p’s) divides $y$?

Comment: @Eric you can repeat the process for any prime factor of $x$ and for any prime factor of $y$ and $z$. If $p^2$ divides $y$ so $p^2$ has to divide $x$ or $z$. Because the numbers are relatively prime this implies that $p^2$ divides $x$

Comment: But you assume that $p$ is prime in, so you can’t “repeat” the  process over on the initial numbers with $p^2$ and it’s not obvious to me from the shown work that you can apply the same thing to $x’,y’$

Comment: @Eric i did a Little modificati in of the formula. Assume now that  $p$ still divide $x'$. Can you see that $p$ has to divide One (and only One) between $y'$ and $z$?  Because It can't divide $z$ It has to divide $y'$ i.e. if $p^2$ divide $x$ so It divide $y$

Comment: Yeah, it’s now clear that you get the back original equation :-)